# flutter - using provider to change font size globally

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm trying to use provider in my flutter app to allow the user to change the font size for some widgets.

I'm following the method described in github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_counter/lib/main.dart but the font size isn't changing.

I have a UI widget which shows plus and minus buttons:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import './size_controller.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class TypeSize extends StatelessWidget {


  final _standardSize = 20.0;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Change type size: ",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: _standardSize),
          ),
          ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 50,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_standardSize < 23.0) {
                    Provider.of<FontSizeController>(context, listen: false).increment(_standardSize);
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  "+", style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 50,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_standardSize > 20.0) {
                    Provider.of<FontSizeController>(context, listen: false).decrement(_standardSize);
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                "-", style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

FontSizeController looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FontSizeController with ChangeNotifier {

  double value = 20.0;

  void increment(value) {
    value ++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement(value) {
    value --;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

and finally the widget that I want to change looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:wfa_ambo_bloc/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../controllers/size_controller.dart';

class Comfort extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ComfortState createState() => _ComfortState();
}

class _ComfortState extends State<Comfort> {

  int _comfortSliderValue = 3;
  // double _standardSize = 20;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
      child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => FontSizeController(),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Consumer<FontSizeController>(
                builder: (
                  context, 
                  sizeController, 
                  child) => Text(
                    "How comfortable was your journey?",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                      fontSize: sizeController.value,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
... etc
```

Nothing is happening when the buttons are clicked. Can anybody help please?

The example that I'm trying to adapt is all contained within the main() but I've separated out my widgets to try and make everything cleaner - is that what is making the difference?

Comment: Hey mate please share your code. I am not able to change the size.

Comment: @Priyank - sure, but there's no room in a comment to put the full code. How best to share? What is happening when you click the resize buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use a variable in your widget (remove `_standardSize`).

Just keep the value in your `ChangeNotifier` and use it directly (through a getter) :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FontSizeController with ChangeNotifier {

  double _value = 20.0;

  int get value => _value;

  void increment() {
    _value++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement() {
    _value--;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Then on plus and minus buttons, simply increment or decrement value from your `ChangeNotifier` :

```dart
// on plus button pressed
Provider.of<FontSizeController>(context, listen: false).increment();

// on minus button pressed
Provider.of<FontSizeController>(context, listen: false).decrement();
```

Finally in the widget where you want your text to be sized :

```dart
fontSize: Provider.of<FontSizeController>(context, listen: true).value
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain... this solution have been tested, it works fine and is far better than using unnecessary variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted either. You were right about not needing to pass the _standardSize variable and your method seems to align with the recommended one at https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_counter/lib/main.dart. What I had to change in my case was location of the ChangeNotifierProvider widget. I got distracted by not polluting the scope and placed it in the UI question widget instead of in main.

Comment: Indeed if you use `Provider.of` then your `ChangeNotifierProvider` have to be moved to an ancestor widget (can be main). I used `Provider.of` to retrieve the value in my answer as an example but of course you can keep using `Consumer` if you prefer (especially if you need more specific widgets rebuilds), and in that case you don't need to move your `ChangeNotifierProvider` to the main. It all depends on your application structure and where you need to access Provider data.

Comment: @Yann39 I think listen should be true : in fontSize: Provider.of<FontSizeController>(context, listen: false).value

Comment: @iamnabink True :)